# how do i obtain system info from my app?

Tags: android

Im making an app for my website, I need to know the system info of whoever installs my app,

I have an email.java Activity class, i am wondering if its possible to add the system info as an attachment or on the bottom of whatever's typed,

I also have a text.java Activity which id like to do same if possible (not attachment)

or someway of me "viewing" the system info when they contact me by email or sms.

Long winded question but any pointer would be very helpful.

Im learning android everyday at the minute as im wanting to get into programming. so bare this is mind when answering.

Thanks

Comment: Precisely what information, and why do you need it?

Comment: Really all i need is the device Model as i repair screens for the devices, i need the Device Model to know the screen size needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Build class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

`Build.DEVICE` or `Build.MODEL` may be what you're looking for.  You can just append that to the end of the text you create in your email Activity.

Comment: Where does that info show though is where im struggling. i need that info either attatched or imported to textview as maybe a signature??

Comment: All of the fields of the Build class return a string.  So if you have a TextView named tv, you could do this. `tv.setText(Build.DEVICE)` or, more generally, `String userDevice = Build.DEVICE` and use that String however you need.  For more specific help as to how to implement this, I would need to see an example of the code where you want to use it.

Comment: how do i send the code to you... new to the site, i dont have to create a new question do i?

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question, it's probably best to post it there.

Comment: tried and failed.. keep getting error contains malformed code.. tried about 6 times lol..

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
 
     String to = textTo.getText().toString();
     String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
     String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

Comment: they are the only strings i have

Comment: It looks like message would be the body of your e-mail. so try `String message = textMessage.getText().toString() + Build.DEVICE`.  This will append the String that contains the user Device to the end of the String that contains your message.  You can also add in spaces or newlines if you need to adjust the format, just use "+" to concatenate your strings.

Comment: that worked a treat mate.. Thankyou very much for your help! Appreciated